# Loading a false Tiled Map (.tmx) using Slick in Java

Tags: java, slick2d, tiled

I try to create a mere 2D game in Java and with my researches I found out that the best motor should be Slick.

I used the softaware Tiled to create the map and try to run my Java program to see the result and after many problem of compression I already solved, it turned out that the map is simply false (the tiles are not placed well).

I tried to change see the .tmx code in a text editor but I found nothing to change.

Here's my Java code I run in Eclipse :

```
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.tiled.*;

public class Lecon_1 extends BasicGame {
GameContainer container;
TiledMap map;
public Lecon_1() {
    super("Lesson 1 :: WindowGame");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException {
    new AppGameContainer(new Lecon_1(), 321, 321, false).start();
}

@Override 
public void init(GameContainer container) throws SlickException {
    this.container = container;
     this.map = new TiledMap("src/map/Essai1.tmx");
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    this.map.render(0, 0);
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException {
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(int key, char c) {
    if (Input.KEY_ESCAPE == key) {
        container.exit();
    }
}
}
```

The Map I created:

[image]

The Map I get after running the code:

[image]

I tried many things and search in a lot of websites but nobody seems to have this problem. It may be a problem from the Slick classes but I don't know which one and don't know why. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance,

Alburkerk

Comment: My guess is that Slick is not interpreting the tileset margin and spacing exactly the same way that Tiled does. Could you also share your tileset image and the parameters you're using?

Comment: Could you share your .tmx with us?